# HowTo reorder items in DataView object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataView object with productID and productName, 
i get all items from Products Table and store them in Cache.
I want to get items that user bought in order he bought them without using another query or joining tables.

ie. 
Products DataView
1. Foo
2. Foo2
3. Foo3

Filtering to ProductsBoughtByUser using RowFilter (productID in (1,3))
UserProducts DataView
1.Foo
3.Foo3

Now user first bought Foo3, how do i reorder items based on correct ( chronological ) Array. ie 3 1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) for DataView.Sort:

```
private void SortByTwoColumns()
{
    // Get the DefaultViewManager of a DataTable.
    DataView view = DataTable1.DefaultView;

    // By default, the first column sorted ascending.
    view.Sort = "State, ZipCode DESC";
}
```

From your original post, it sounds like you only have Product ID and Product Name.  You can't sort these in memory unless you're also retrieving a purchase/order date.

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to add the date column (PurchaseDate) to your sql statement that you're already using, then do a `view.Sort = "PurchaseDate DESC";`

That way, you don't have to write another statement or hit the database a second time for this sort.

Edit:
The DataRowView has integral and string indexers. e.g.:

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dataView)
{ 
   var value = row["COLUMN_NAME"]; 
}
```

The column is stored as an object, so you'll have to check for null and convert to your data type

Comment: User items are saved in session in purchaseDate order, ie. 3 , 1
It's not a DataView.Sort and it does not have PurchaseDate to sort based on

Comment: @eugeneK: If you don't want to add the necessary column to perform the sort, you'll have to reconstruct the dataview entirely. It will sort on a FIFO concept, so if they bought Foo3 first, you'll need to create a new datatable with the row for Foo3 and follow it with the row for Foo1.

Comment: Thanks Joel my question was how i do that, how do i manipulate DataView and get certain row ?
I can run for loop on Array with proper order, while orders[i] needs to be retrieved from DataView and added to DataTable... It's more a question of that i don't know to get data from DataView's row...

thanks

Comment: @eugene, you DataRowView has integral and string indexers. e.g.:  `foreach (DataRowView row in dataView){ var value = row["COLUMN_NAME"]; }`  The column is stored as an object, so you'll have to check for null and convert to your data type.